# Fail2ban Dynamic IP

Tags: fail2ban

I need help setting up my Fail2ban. I have a client that your IP is Dynamic.

and every time I need to wait for it to tell me the IP so I can include ignoreip.

How can i make a script to collect if user exceeds maxretry= 5. Your domain is @ myexample.com so release this ip in iptables?

I researched several topics on the subject, most of them about including your own dynamic IP. In this case it's the dynamic IP of the client, because my ip is fixed. Thanks for the space and sorry if I'm posting in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4):

For ignoreip fail2ban can take an ip or a dns name.
See https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist

So, since your client does not have a fixed ip, he should register to a service like dyndns.org and get a dns name for his internet dynamic ip.
See https://dyn.com/dns/

Lets say it will be `fernandoclient.dyndns.org`

Simply add this hostname to the `ignoreip` list in the Fail2ban `jail.conf` file.
Like this

```
[DEFAULT]
# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not                          
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be                             
# defined using space separator.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 fernandoclient.dyndns.org
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.

I set my fixed IP local with the correct client DNS name?

But the client IP is dynamic and always changes ...

Today his IP is 177.47.240.0 ... yesterday it was .215.73.163 ...

Comment: @Fernando : Please reread, i gave you a solution which will solve the problem you are facing